# post about ice cream deleted

Tags: discussion

My recent post in
[Is there a magic ingredient that keeps ice-cream soft?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12777/is-there-a-magic-ingredient-that-keeps-ice-cream-soft/33553?noredirect=1#comment47287_33553) was deleted from Jeromi.

I would say that i was expecting that, because I knew I was not answering to the question. In fact, I was expecting negative votes, but that is better to me.

I'm sorry, but being Italian I could not resist. =)
And I find absolutely right the punitive action. And I thank you Jeromi for your kindness, which I find here anywhere.

To return to the post, a comment is not interesting, if not for me (exactly as the deleted post was). At the end I said mine, but if I were a person not so passionate, I would have shut up.

I knew perfectly well I was making a mistake and I apologize for the time that I hid.
Thank you again for your kindness.

Cordially.

Comment: Many of us are passionate about food here...  you might want to join us from time to time in the chat, where there are no rules about what is on topic or off topic.   If you think a certain question is interesting and helpful (in this, case for example, how can gelato have a soft texture without stabilizers or gums?, you are welcome to enter the question and an answer.   You could then add a comment in the related question, saying See also: XXX to reference the related question.

Comment: You also definitely don't need to apologize. Closing and deletion is part of the normal everyday process here and doesn't constitute any kind of a mark against you (it's certainly not punitive). Though we certainly appreciate your candor.

Comment: If you are able to effort my definately horrible english, I'll come willingly into the chat - ant thanks for invitation =)

Comment: how can I enter a question about "good italian ice cream", in a very polite way, and (waiting first answers), answer myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't phrased this as a question, but I'll go ahead an interpret it as a fuzzy one about what the right thing to do in this case was!

- If you ever want to tell me something, you can also simply ping me in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) - prefix a message with @Jefromi and I'll be notified! (And I'll come in and reply when I have a chance.)
- I'm glad you're passionate enough about your ice cream and your Italianness to want to contribute! In the future, if you feel a comment isn't enough, do note that you can also ask and answer your own question! Your answer might've been appropriate for a question about how to serve soft ice cream without any special ingredients, for example. Though in this case, I don't think you'd need to ask another question - there's already a bit of a mess of soft ice cream questions, and perhaps one of the existing ones would be a good home. (You should still be able to see your deleted answer, should you want to copy and paste it somewhere new.)
- I'm glad you thought I was kind! But really, you should expect that. I'm a new mod and trying to be a good one - so feel free to call me out on it if you think I'm *not* being nice enough. (Now that I've posted this for posterity here, I should also add: sometimes mods do have to be make final judgments, be firm, and do things like deleting content, and I'll of course still do those things - I'll just try to be polite about it.)

Comment: sorry I am very new (newbeing) I am learning some thing at once. Never tried the chat. And, ok, you are a new mod and I am a new user. Welcome among mods ;-). In fact, I didnt found very gentle persons in this section (you are the first one). Since i though to abandone it. But i love cooking, i write about cooking and finally I can learn new things too. So see you soon, gentle mod =) - (Of course I am passionate about ice cream, leave to you your hot dog) :P